# I upgraded to iOS 4.3.5 on iPad and despite creating a Symlink, can no longer debug on device

Tags: debugging, ios4, xcode4

My MacBook Pro has
Mac OS X 10.6.8
XCode 4.0 Build 4A304a

I updated the iOS to 4.3.5 (8L1) on my iPad
Since that update, I am unable to debug on iPad.

I get:

warning: Unable to read symbols for
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)
   /Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

I believed that I need to make a symlink to the latest version of
    libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib

So I did:

cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols  // corrected with backslashes
sudo ln -s ../../4.1/Symbols/Developer/ Developer

Since creating the symlink, I now get instead a message telling of a UUID error

What should I do to get debugging back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Framework in your xcode project a libxml2.dylib. I think the "problem" because of xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 beta.

Answer (score 0):

Search in the warnings, it happened to me when I was trying to print a variable